# How to display data in DataGridView like flight information display

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that displays data from MS Access in DataGridView by Timers
I put 2 dgvs in my Form and each one should display different data from different tables.
my dgv displays 14 rows (that's the full size of monitor!).
here is what i tried:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub  
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        getDATA(dgv1, dgv2, Timer1, Timer2, "tab1")
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        getDATA(dgv2, dgv1, Timer2, Timer1, "tab2")
End Sub
Private Sub getDATA(dgv As DataGridView, vdgv As DataGridView, tm1 As Timer, tm2 As Timer, tbl As String)
    Try
        dgv.Visible = True
        vdgv.Visible = False
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then conn.Close()
        Dim sqlstr As String = ""
        sqlstr = "Select f1,f2,f3,f4 from " + tbl
        Dim ds As New DataTable
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstr, conn)
        ds.Reset()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstr, conn)
        da.Fill(ds)
        conn.Open()
        If ds.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            dgv.Rows.Clear()
        Else
            dgv.Rows.Clear()
            dgv.Rows.Add(ds.Rows.Count)
            For s = 0 To ds.Rows.Count - 1
                dgv.Rows(s).Cells(0).Value = ds.Rows(s).Item("f1")
                dgv.Rows(s).Cells(1).Value = ds.Rows(s).Item("f2")
                dgv.Rows(s).Cells(2).Value = ds.Rows(s).Item("f3")
                dgv.Rows(s).Cells(3).Value = ds.Rows(s).Item("f4")
            Next s
        End If
        dgv.ClearSelection()
        conn.Close()
        tm1.Stop()
        tm2.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This code is work fine, but sometimes one of the tables contains more than 14 rows!
how can i display the rest of rows in specific DGV?
should i use another Timer?

Comment: why not add a `For i As Integer = 0 To 13 'AddRow Next` Or you can use the `LIMIT` keyword in your select to only get 14 rows

Comment: if i use LIMIT or TOP, what about the rest rows?

Comment: If you want to be able to go through the rows just store all your rows in an array and display the first 14 results and on button click display next 14 etc